# How to populate one column in a table from another table column [Magento OOP way]

Tags: magento-enterprise, mysql, setup-script, script, zend-framework

I am new to magento. I have to perform a db task in magento upgrade script which should be done using magento OOP db way. But i cannot figure it out how to do it. I can do it in plain sql query but need someone's help to point out how to do it in magento's way.

Here is my sql qeury which i am running in magento and works fine but i need to do it magento's way. Any help is appreciated. I am not just looking fro a code. I need some explaination as well please.

```
$installer->startSetup();
$sql = "UPDATE Ecom_order eo, sales_flat_order sfo
        SET eo.order_status = sfo.status
        WHERE eo.order_id = sfo.entity_id";

$conn = $installer->getConnection();
$conn->query($sql);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: is it that hard to do this in Magento? No one to help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution anyone needs this. I found the reference from Magento core setup files.

```
//select
$select = $installer->getConnection()->select()
        ->from(
            array('eo' => $my_table)
        );
//join
$select->reset()
        ->joinLeft(
            array('sfo' => $installer->getTable('sales/order')),
            "eo.order_id = sfo.entity_id",
            array('order_status' => 'sfo.status')
        );
//update query from select
$updateSql = $select->crossUpdateFromSelect(array('eo' => $my_table));

//run query
$installer->getConnection()->query($updateSql);
```

Comment: If your answer solves your problem, then please accept it, so as people having the same issue come to your solution.

Comment: Thanks i did not know that. Just accepted it since this did solve my problem.